# Trying to understand python regular expression end of string matching with \Z, \b, $ vs just ending the expression

Tags: python, regex, string, match

Setup: I have a regular expression that matches people's names that have stray punctuation at the end, unless that punctuation belongs there as part of single-letter initials.  So, "Lincoln, Abe." should match, and "Lincoln, A." should not.  I have written an expression that works fine for me, but I am puzzled as to why my previous attempt did not work.

Query: I'd like to figure out why I need to include an end-of-string anchor to my regular expression.
Here are expressions that successfully match, the way I'd expect:

```
(Pdb) re.compile("(.*)(\w{2,})([?:.,;]*?)\Z").match("abc,. def....").groups()
('abc,. d', 'ef', '....')
(Pdb) re.compile("(.*)(\w{2,})([?:.,;]*?)\b").match("abc,. def....").groups()
*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
(Pdb) re.compile("(.*)(\w{2,})([?:.,;]*?)$").match("abc,. def....").groups()
('abc,. d', 'ef', '....')
```

I think that I should also be able to match my word without ending my regular expression in an end-of-string character.  However, only the first two groups are acknowledged, the third is returned empty:

```
(Pdb) re.compile("(.*)(\w{2,})([?:.,;]*?)").match("abc,. def....").groups()
('abc,. d', 'ef', '')
```

I've looked at questions dealing with end-of-string matching on SO and at the api docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).  So far, I don't quite understand, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*?` means a non-greedy match, so it will match as few characters as possible. When it’s required to be followed by the end of the string, it’s forced to keep matching, but if you remove that restriction then it has no obligation to match anything at all (and doesn’t).

A simplified example:

```
# non-greedy
re.search(r'^.*?$', 'hello world').group() == 'hello world'
re.search(r'^.*?l', 'hello world').group() == 'hel'
re.search(r'^.*?', 'hello world').group() == ''

# greedy
re.search(r'^.*$', 'hello world').group() == 'hello world'
re.search(r'^.*l', 'hello world').group() == 'hello worl'
re.search(r'^.*', 'hello world').group() == 'hello world'
```

Comment: So python evaluates regex left-to-right, unless there's an anchor at the right boundary?  And match and search functions are not obliged to match the whole string, but can match any part within, so the regex is not automatically anchored to the right?

Comment: @user3204300: To your second question, yes; to your first, kind of. The regex engine has to find the leftmost match. There is no “unless there’s an anchor at the right boundary”; anchors behave the same way as any other part of the regex.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I think I got it.